# hive command - Show tables or any command not working

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, remote-connections

I am unable to run *any* queries from the `hive>` shell. For example, even something simple such as

```
hive> select * from date;
```

produces the same error after parsing is complete:

> select * from date
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ASTNode.setUnknownTokenBoundaries()V
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:214)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:166)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:389)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:303)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1067)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1129)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1004)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:994)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:247)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:199)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:410)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:783)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:677)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:616)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)

---

Here are the logs:

> 15/09/02 08:55:12 [main]: INFO hive.metastore: Connected to metastore.
>   15/09/02 08:55:12 [main]: INFO session.SessionState: Created local directory: /home/ETRI/hive/tmpdir/ETRI/f128f3e2-998f-4463-aa1b-8649db186945_resources
>   15/09/02 08:55:12 [main]: INFO session.SessionState: Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/ETRI/f128f3e2-998f-4463-aa1b-8649db186945
>   15/09/02 08:55:12 [main]: INFO session.SessionState: Created local directory: /home/ETRI/hive/tmpdir/ETRI/f128f3e2-998f-4463-aa1b-8649db186945
>   15/09/02 08:55:13 [main]: INFO session.SessionState: Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/ETRI/f128f3e2-998f-4463-aa1b-8649db186945/_tmp_space.db
>   15/09/02 08:55:13 [main]: INFO session.SessionState: No Tez session required at this point. hive.execution.engine=mr.
>   15/09/02 08:55:13 [main]: INFO log.PerfLogger: 
>   15/09/02 08:55:13 [main]: INFO log.PerfLogger: 
>   15/09/02 08:55:13 [main]: INFO ql.Driver: Concurrency mode is disabled, not creating a lock manager
>   15/09/02 08:55:13 [main]: INFO log.PerfLogger: 
>   15/09/02 08:55:13 [main]: INFO log.PerfLogger: 
>   15/09/02 08:55:13 [main]: INFO parse.ParseDriver: Parsing command: show tables
>   15/09/02 08:55:13 [main]: INFO parse.ParseDriver: Parse Completed
>   15/09/02 08:55:13 [main]: INFO log.PerfLogger:

---

I have managed the configurations as per the below link.

[cloudera Mysql hive config](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh4/v4-2-0/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_18_4.html)

---

I am wondering how to handle this `setUnknownTokenBoundaries()V` method?

I didn't change any methods in ql.parse, as these are internal.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the issue with Hive or mysql connector.

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError occurs when compiling against one version of a library but running against a different version. Try updating the Java version and set the environmental variables on Hadoop and try running Hive.

Comment: Thanks a lot! yes. I was using java 1.7 and hive 0.14, may be compiler is unable to pick the code I had in hive 0.14. So updated the java 1.8 and used hive again.. and here we go it worked.!!!

Comment: Also I believe this doesnt mean that hive 0.14 runs only in java 1.8. It can also run in java 1.7. May be its because the hive I am using was already used for java 1.8 in other system.

Anyway, Issue solved now. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem stated can also be a more general issue with Hive and its dependency on ANTLR. In my case, the issue occurs not because of some environment variable but because of ANTLR being included on the classpath of an application that's using Spark including Hive and its dependencies.

ASTNode (part of Hive) is extending CommonTree (part of ANTLR). It inherits the method `setUnknownTokenBoundaries` which is present in newer versions of ANTLR like 3.5.x but not there in 3.1.x. Sorting out the ANTLR dependencies solved the problem.